# How to fix 'no entries found' on server run in Parcel.js

Tags: parceljs

On trying to run the server with 'parcel index.js':

> Server running at http://localhost:1234    No entries found.
>       at Bundler.bundle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Bundler.js:275:17)

Server is showing a 404 error. I'm having the same problem with all my projects, so I feel like this is a global issue. Everything was working fine on all projects and suddenly this is occurring.

already tried:

- uninstalling parcel-bundler and reinstalling (globally + locally)

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple mistake, was using "parcel index.js" when I should have been using "parcel *index.html*"

Comment: Hello, where in the code is "parcel index.js"?

Comment: @AmandaKoster it's not in the code, it's a command run on the terminal/command line.

Answer (score 9):

As above check the directory from which you are working i was inside src and running `src/parcel index.html` it should be `parcel index.html`

Answer (score 8):

Mine was typing `parcel /src/index.html` instead of `parcel src/index.html`. Spent 20 minutes on this.......

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question and is therefore not really an appropriate form to share this type of information.

Comment: I had the same problem, this fixed it! The instructions I was following was missing a character - thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

My mistake on windows was that I used `parcel src/index.html` instead of `parcel src\index.html`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are running parcel in a subfile of a project, so you need to add the path relative to the root directory,my path is `parcel Navigation-webpage/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
npm i @parcel/transformer-sass
```

And update parcel bundler .

```
npm i parcel
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've got all your filenames in the explorer view spelled correctly. That was my solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same error.

And please check json file:

```
"source" : "src/index.html"
```

It's source instead of main.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by discovering my mistake at first

when I created the project main folder and then created the /src folder by mistake I created the index.html in the main folder, not inside the /src folder
and when I do npm run dev I get this error
[Build failed.unknown: Entry Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB2Ma.png)

So to fix that I moved the files [index.html - main.scss - widget.js] to the src folder, So now it looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHiaX.png)
And it works

> Important hint here because it happened to me too: after you move the
> files and try again with "npm run dev" you will get an error and the
> reason why is that you need first to change all the directories of the
> imported files in the [index.html], like main.css app.js and the
> images too before running parcel again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error by adding the path to the entry point file explicitly in `package.json`.

For example, in the `"scripts"` section:

```
"start": "parcel ./folder_name/file_name.html"
```

With this, you can run `npm run start` and Parcel may run more smoothly if other answers here aren't fully resolving the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + c, exit from that console.
Then delete .parcel-cache, dist folder.
npx parcel index.html