# Parcel - No entries found

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, parcel

Why does `parcel start` throw a no entries found error? I looked online and found that parcel can't find the index.html, but I don't understand why. I have a index.html file in the root folder. Is there anything I'm missing?

**package.json**

```
{
      "name": "meep.io",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.html",
      "dependencies": {
        "pixi.js": "^5.2.0",
        "typescript": "^3.7.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "parcel index.html",
        "watch": "parcel watch index.html"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      canvas {
        display: block;
        background: grey;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">
        You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please
        <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.
      </p>
    <![endif]-->
    <canvas id="game-canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="./src/app.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See also [How to fix 'no entries found' on server run in Parcel.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948356/how-to-fix-no-entries-found-on-server-run-in-parcel-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `parcel start` instead of `npm run start`

Comment: I was doing the same thing! I need to run `yarn start`.

Answer (score 6):

In my case put source via package.json makes things work.

```
{
   ..  
   "source": "index.html",
   ..
}
```

[Official docs with more params](https://parceljs.org/features/targets/#entries)

Comment: I did this and also removed `"main": "index.js"`